# How to convert ebook in Calibre?

Tags: calibre

How do you convert an ebook to a different format in Calibre?

If I select a book, click the big "Convert Books" button, select output to "MOBI", and click "OK", it appears to run a job successfully, but no new ebook format is generated.

If I click on the jobs, and show details for the last job run, the final line in the log is:

```
 MOBI output written to /tmp/calibre_5.9.0_tmp_q1zebnlm/v8c6whw0.mobi
```

But that file does not exist.

Where is it putting the file?

Comment: Look in home for **Calibre Library**. They should all be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Convert an E-book to a Different Format in Calibre

The first time you open an E-book in Calibre you are asked to specify a location for the library and are offered a default location of home/username/Calibre Library.

This is probably the first place to start looking.

You can also open a text file in Calibre and convert it to .epub, then see were that ends up.